# Azure VM with Bit-locker now fails to decrypt due to Azure Key Vault internal error?

Tags: powershell, azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Key Vault physical HSM and 3 VMs deployed to an ARM resource group within a region.  2 VMs are Win Server 2012 with BitLocker extension encrypted via Key Vault.  1 VM is linux (not encrypted) with no problem.  Windows machines starting and stopping daily and working fine until yesterday they failed to start.  No feedback from the portal but on Powershell gives the error:

```
"InnerError": null,

"Code": "DiskEncryptionInternalError",

"Message": "Unknown error encountered when retrieving https://....vault.azure.net/secrets/..... from the Key Vault.",
```

Application and credentials & key vault permissions remain current.  Azure Key Vault service for the region is showing as "healthy".  I'm awaiting support request response.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  I hope Azure can save my machines.

Comment: If you go to the old portal and into your AAD and find the application you are using... On the Configure tab what are the expiration dates on the keys listed there?

Comment: Good idea Greg, but the application is current with 12 months to run.  Both machines use the same application but this hasn't been a problem in over a month of testing.

Answer (score 0):

Aravind and others from Microsoft were upfront and professional in resolving the issue that gave rise to the error listed.  Well done thanks.